# Guide in understanding code - Splitting array on smaller arrays

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a problem with understanding one process which is splitting array on smaller arrays. I'm posting the two lines below and I would appreciate if you could explain to me what certain part does. Thank you in advance :)

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 

# How many elements each 
# list should have 
n = 4 

final = [my_list[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(my_list) + n - 1) // n )]  


# Almost the same code with some changes:
def split_list(alist, wanted_parts=1):
    length = len(alist)
    return [ alist[i*length // wanted_parts: (i+1)*length // wanted_parts] 
             for i in range(wanted_parts) ]

A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: This question is too broad, please can you ask a more specific question about the part of the code you don't understand. What is your expected output vs what you are getting?

Comment: @NickMartin I know the output, but I need to know what all "final" does

Comment: In this code, `final` is just a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is your problem?
you have the initial list

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

for example, you want to split it on 3 parts. So you call function

```
split_list(my_list, wanted_parts =3)
```

inside function, you will have:

```
length = len(alist) # it will be 9
```

then you have this:

```
for i in range(wanted_parts)  # range(3), so it would be i = [0,1,2]
```

then you have:

```
alias[xxxx:yyyy] # where xxxx - start point of slice and yyyy - end point of slice, and you have it 3 times and pass there i = (0,1,2)
```

now lets check xxxx. in your case it is:

```
i*length // wanted_parts  # i=0..2, length = 9, wanted_parts = 3, so all of this = 0, 3, 6
```

now lets check yyyy. in your case it is:

```
(i+1)*length // wanted_parts. # i = 0..2, (i+1) = 1..3, length = 9, wanted_parts = 3, so all of this = 3, 6, 9
```

so totaly you will have:

```
[0:3], [3:6], [6:9] # - and it will be 3 parts of your list
```